# Application crashes with wake lock and power manager

Tags: android, wakelock

I create an application for use flash LED android as torch or as strobe light and add wake lock and power manager for not sleep.But when the user go to menu setup my apk crashed.Without wake lock work fine!How i fix it?

```
private PowerManager.WakeLock wl;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "Flash Strobe");

        // .......................
        case R.id.menu_setup:
            stopTask();//stop timer repeat blink
            if (camera != null) {
                camera.release();
            } 
            wl.release();
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Setup.class));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

LogCat:

```
W/ServiceManager(148): Permission failure: com.sonyericsson.permission.CAMERA_EXTENDED from uid=10151 pid=24623
f_button_handler button callback not registered
```

Comment: Show log cat, Did you add the permission?

Comment: Wake lock permission is ok...work fine until user go to setup menu...

Comment: E/wpa_supplicant(7733): Unsupported command: SETSUSPENDOPT 0

Comment: W/ServiceManager(148): Permission failure: com.sonyericsson.permission.CAMERA_EXTENDED from uid=10151 pid=24623

Comment: f_button_handler button callback not registered

Comment: @Antonis Kan Have you tried on the emulator or another phone? It looks like the permission is Sony Ericsson specific. Also post your manifest. I believe you have not added the right permission.

Comment: My problem is when go to setup not with camera...In main activity camera led flash work fine!!!